# Limite de carácteres em input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quero montar um jQuery que aplique um limite de 255 carácteres dentro do `input`.

Minha ideia e fazer algo assim:

```
$(".loading").on('input', function () {
  // aqui eu tenho que fazer o bloqueio
});
```

Comment: Pq vc não usa o maxlength: `<input type="text" name="usrname" maxlength="255">`

Comment: pos tenho um projeto que já esta pronto, se eu for colocar `maxlength` vai levar muito tempo. sendo que alguns input já possui `maxlength` menor.

Comment: entendi, acredito q a resposta do @Mathias vai te ajudar.. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gostaria de sugerir algumas modificações ao que já foi proposto:

- Primeiro `keydown` funciona bem, mas existe a limitação, mas se for usá-lo terá que combinar `onpaste` e `oninput` (ou ondrop talvez, se for arrastar algo) também.
- Segundo, o evento `.on` do jQuery talvez seja melhor aplicado se for usado em um "contexto", ou seja ao invés disto `$(seletor).on(function())` usar isto `$(document).on(seletor, function())`, pois desta maneira o jQuery detecta melhor as modificações no DOM por exemplo páginas em Ajax

No geral recomendo trocar por `onchange` (`propertychange` para versões antigas do IE) e remover o que for adicionado posteriormente:

```js
(function () {

    var limite = 10;
    
    function limitaInput(input) {
        if (input.value.length > limite) {
            input.value = input.value.substr(0, limite);
        }
    }
    
    $(document).on("propertychange change keyup", ".loading", function () {
        if (this.timerLimitInput) {
           clearTimeout(this.timer);
        }
    
        this.timerLimitInput = setTimeout(limitaInput, 10, this);//Timeout para evitar conflitos
    });

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<input class="loading">
```

Desta maneira qualquer manipulação no `<input>` será detectada

Answer (score 6):

Existem muitas formas de fazer isso, como a @Jessika comentou:

```
<input type="text" class="loading" maxlength="255">
```

Caso queira fazer o mesmo, utilizando jquery

```
function limitaCampo(campo, tamanho){
    $(campo).attr('maxlength',tamanho);
}
```

Caso queira fazer da maneira como tu apresentou: só mudar de `'input'` para `'keydown'`:

```
$(".loading").on('keydown', function (e) {
   if($(this).val().length >= 255){
      return false;
   }
});
```

Segue um snippet com limite de 2 caracteres:

*adicionei `e.keyCode != 8 e 9` p/ permitir o click no <kbd>backspace</kbd> e no <kbd>TAB</kbd>

```js
$(".loading").on('keydown', function(e) {
  if ($(this).val().length >= 2 && e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 9) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="loading">
```

Comment: Boa dica do keyCode !=8, não esqueça do TAB também

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento perfeito, adicionado à resposta, ty.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o evento `keydown` ao invés de `input` e usar um atributo `data-*` para definir o limite (já que você disse nos comentários que não pode "confiar" no atributo `maxlength`.

A implementação tá bem ingênua, mas a ideia é essa.

```js
$(".loading").on('keydown', function (evt) {
  var qtd = $(this).val().length;
  var limite = $(this).data('limite') || 255;

  if(qtd > limite && evt.keyCode != 8)
    return false;
  
  console.log(qtd, limite);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="loading" data-limite="10"></textarea>
<textarea class="loading"></textarea>
```